# Not able to see statistics when table is created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am reading white paper on statistics,but i am not able to get answers to few questions

--code to Reproduce the issue

```
CREATE TABLE stats_update
  (
     id   INT IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK__stats_up__3213E83FCCAB6EF5 PRIMARY KEY,
     name CHAR(20) DEFAULT 'a'
  )

--check for stats
EXEC sp_helpstats 'stats_update'

go
--insert two values
INSERT INTO stats_update
DEFAULT VALUES

go 2

--check for stats
EXEC sp_helpstats
  'stats_update',
  'all'

SELECT *
FROM   stats_update

--lets create an index now on name 
CREATE INDEX nci_test
  ON dbo.stats_update(name)

--check for stats
EXEC sp_helpstats
  'stats_update',
  'all'

--lets see when we stats last updated
DBCC show_Statistics ('stats_update', 'PK__stats_up__3213E83FCCAB6EF5')

go
--now lets insert some  rows
INSERT INTO stats_update
DEFAULT VALUES

go 200
--lets check stats again
--check for stats
exec sp_helpstats 'stats_update', 'all'

DBCC show_Statistics ('stats_update', 'PK__stats_up__3213E83FCCAB6EF5')

SELECT *
FROM   sys.stats
WHERE  object_id = object_id('stats_update')


go

INSERT INTO stats_update
DEFAULT VALUES

go 2000

SELECT *
FROM   stats_update

SELECT *
FROM   stats_update
WHERE  id = 10 

DBCC show_Statistics ('stats_update', 'PK__stats_up__3213E83FCCAB6EF5')
```

**Updated as per comments**
**QUESTION:**
I could not see histogram populated at any stage of the above script,Histogram is getting populated only after rebuilding index or doing update stats.Can some one help me understand why

Comment: This is a demo about the 500 rows (+ some percentage) update limit for stats update?

Comment: "QUESTION" would look more natural than "ASK" as a header :-)

Comment: This was asked long time back,i couldnt delete it .Updated question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but none of the operations that your script perform require detailed statistics on `id` column to be created.

Your script performs

```
INSERT INTO stats_update
DEFAULT VALUES; /*Doesn't need column stats on id*/

SELECT *
FROM   stats_update /*Table cardinality is stored separately*/

SELECT *
FROM   stats_update
WHERE  id = 10  /*Unique constraint so can assume 1 row*/
```

If you change the predicate to something like the below then stats are created.

```
SELECT *
FROM   stats_update
WHERE  id > 10
```

Comment: Hi Martin,Sorry.I have edited the question,i could see histogram populated only after i rebuild index.

Comment: @TheGameiswar that is explained in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Martin,i have used =10 ,i will test for >10 and will test.Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Martin.there is some confusion.thanks for your help